# Trying different pseudo-classes for links?

Tags: html, css, button, pseudo-class

i'm new at coding and I have what I seems a simple problem but I can't fix it.

I have a link with a button format and now all the links in my document are shown like a button.

```css
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:  'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: rgb(55, 89, 238);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
        <a href="emailto:my@mail.com">Contact me</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>Now I want to add a normal link but it looks like
<a href="page.php">a button</a></p>
</div>
```

Edit:
I want to know how can I make the other links in my site look normal?

Comment: hi there, can you please explain more about your issue was ?

Comment: The :link CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has not yet been visited. It matches every unvisited <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a css descendant selector that will include the button and the link to target that "button link" only, which will leave all the other links alone. When you use .button and a:link with only a space between, it looks for the two of them together, and thinks they are related like descendants. Here's how to do this:

```css
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:  'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.button a:link, .button a:visited {
    background-color: rgb(55, 89, 238);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
        <a href="emailto:my@mail.com">Contact me</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>Now I want to add a normal link but it looks like
<a href="page.php">a button</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you apply style to **all** `a`  that you have in your `HTML`

**to prevent it** you have to **spesific**  those `button` or `a` by add `class` or `id` attribute and set for them style in css(for class you have to add `.` before the class name  in css (`.className`) and for id `#` (`#idName`)):

Learn here about selector in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
.button{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:  'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.spesificA:link, .spesificA:visited {
    background-color: rgb(55, 89, 238);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
        <a href="emailto:my@mail.com" class="spesificA">Contact me</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>Now I want to add a normal link but it looks like
<a href="page.php">a button not spesific class(without style)</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!